# Send a list of objects over Azure service bus

Tags: azure, appfabric, azureservicebus

I'm trying to send a list of objects over the Azure service bus, and want to check this is the correct way to do it. Intially I tried sending:

```
IEnumerable<Product>
```

The Listener endpoint had product objects in the collection, but when it got to the calling endpoint the count was 0. Same for List (which I expected)

I've got it working by using List of BrokeredMessage

```
        List<BrokeredMessage> messages = new List<BrokeredMessage>();

        foreach (BcsProduct product in products)
        {
            BcsProduct p = new BcsProduct { ProductId = product.ProductId, Name = product.Name };
            messages.Add(new BrokeredMessage(p));
        }
```

I wanted to check this was the correct approach, or if IEnumerable should work...

Thanks

Nick

Comment: I've tried it again and it seems sending a List<> of products over the Service Bus does work OK. Not sure what error I had last time, but this question should be deleted

Answer (score 1):

See you have already found the answer, but you could simplifly your code:

```
    List<BrokeredMessage> messages = new List<BrokeredMessage>();

    foreach (BcsProduct product in products)
    {
        messages.Add(new BrokeredMessage(product));
    }
```